# Is it valid to inline variable length arrays in structs by over-allocating memory?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, var, undefined-behavior

I have a struct that I would like to keep in contiguous memory, so that I can be able to `memcpy` the entire structure etc. However my structure contains an array of variable length. **Now this length will be *fixed for the duration of the program execution*, but at compile time it is unknown.** Can I get around this by over allocating memory following the struct to make room for the array?

So if I started with

```
struct license_plate{
    char issuing_province_territory_code [2];
    char* number;
}
```

I would need a separate `malloc` for the `number` so I thought of doing the following

```
struct license_plate_v2 {
    char issuing_province_territory_code [3];
    char number[1];
}
```

and allocate it as such

```
size_t sizeof_license_plate_v2( int number_length ){
    return sizeof(struct license_plate_v2) + number_length * sizeof(char);
}


struct license_plate_v2* malloc_license_plate_v2( int number_length ){
    return malloc( sizeof_license_plate_v2( number_length ) );
}
```

and then be able to iterate over an array like

```
struct license_plate_v2* index_license_plate_v2( struct license_plate_v2 *arr, int index, int plate_num_len ){
    return  arr + index * sizeof_license_plate_v2(plate_num_len);
}

void print_all( struct license_plate_v2* plates, int num_of_plates, int plate_num_len ){
    for( int plate_index = 0; plate_index < num_of_plates; plate_index++ ){
        struct license_plate_v2* plate = index_license_plate_v2( plates, plate_index, plate_num_len );
        printf( "where: %s, plate: %s\n", plate->issuing_province_territory_code, plate->number  );
    }
}
```

Is this valid C? Is this guaranteed to work or am I using undefined behaviour? Is there any issue with byte alignment if the array is of structs? Is there a term for this? Is this the right way to achieve this sort of effect?

It seems work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    //these values could have from from argv for example
    int num_len = 7;


    struct license_plate_v2 *arr = malloc( 4  * sizeof_license_plate_v2(num_len) );

    struct license_plate_v2 *arr_0 = arr + 0 * sizeof_license_plate_v2(num_len);
    memcpy( arr_0->issuing_province_territory_code, "ON"      , 3           * sizeof(char) );
    memcpy( arr_0->number                         , "BFKK281" , (num_len+1) * sizeof(char) );

    struct license_plate_v2 *arr_1 = arr + 1 * sizeof_license_plate_v2(num_len);
    memcpy( arr_1->issuing_province_territory_code, "ON"      , 3           * sizeof(char) );
    memcpy( arr_1->number                         , "BYTR741" , (num_len+1) * sizeof(char) );

    struct license_plate_v2 *arr_2 = arr + 2 * sizeof_license_plate_v2(num_len);
    memcpy( arr_2->issuing_province_territory_code, "ON"      , 3           * sizeof(char) );
    memcpy( arr_2->number                         , "CAAA224" , (num_len+1) * sizeof(char) );

    struct license_plate_v2 *arr_3 = arr + 3 * sizeof_license_plate_v2(num_len);
    memcpy( arr_3->issuing_province_territory_code, "ON"      , 3           * sizeof(char) );
    memcpy( arr_3->number                         , "CASD431" , (num_len+1) * sizeof(char) );

    print_all( arr, 4, 7 );

    free( arr );   
}
```

---

PS- this is a simplified example to illustrate the question, the real world problem involves something like up to millions of locations with thousands (run but not compile time constant) of data points each of which is a struct not a `char`, so some of the obvious work arounds don't apply.

Comment: Shouldn't `num_len` be 7 in the above example code?

Comment: Yes. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Alignment would be a problem. Even though both members you show in your `struct` are arrays of `char`, and `char` is required (by the C standard) to have the weakest alignment, the structure itself could have a greater alignment requirement. C requires all pointers to structures to have the same representations, and a C implementation might choose to satisfy this in part by requiring all structures to have some minimum alignment.

Comment: This is known as "the struct hack" and is not well-defined. You are looking for _flexible array members_.

Comment: @Lundin: The struct hack was unambiguously defined and supported by the vast majority of implementations of, and relied upon by many programs written, in, *the pre-existing language the C89 Standard was written to describe*.  Given the Standards Committee's charter, they would have presumably intended that it be regarded as one of the "popular extensions" they alluded to for which support would be a "quality of implementation" issue, though many implementations might not have particularly thought that continued support for something that had been well-defined was really an "extension".

Comment: @supercat I wonder how many 1980s computers there were which had struct padding/alignment requirements and virtual memory addresses though. If a struct has no padding and you can write to trailing physical memory cells without problems, then the C standard can say what it will, because it won't matter.

Comment: @Lundin: The 68000 was a popular target for C compilers; it required that all data types that were 16 bits or longer be located at even addresses.  As for whether the C Standard matters, aggressive optimizers use the Standard as an excuse to behave nonsensically without regard for whether the "popular extensions" [sensible behaviors] supported by earlier compilers would be more useful than phony "optimizations" which will seldom offer any performance benefit outside contrived scenarios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Structs with a **flexible array member** cannot be an element of an array.  This is dictated in section 6.7.2.1p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or
>   function type (hence, a structure shall not contain an instance of
>   itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance of  itself),  except 
>   that  the  last  member  of  a  structure  with  more  than  one 
>   named  member may  have  incomplete  array  type;  such  a  structure 
>   (and  any  union  containing,  possibly recursively, a member that is
>   such a structure) shall not be a member of a structure or an element
>   of an array

The reason for this is that array indexing is done by pointing to a memory location that is a  multiple of the size of the struct.  But if the struct has a variable size, there's no way to know where the next instance of a struct is located in memory.

In your particular case, the maximum length of a license plate number is not that large, so just use a fixed size large enough to hold any value it may contain.

```
struct license_plate{
    char issuing_province_territory_code[3];
    char number[20];
}
```

Also, the way you set up a flexible array member with an array of size 1 is the old way of doing this before they were standardized, and it often referred to as "the struct hack".  The modern way of declaring a flexible array member is with an unspecified size:

```
struct license_plate_v2 {
    char issuing_province_territory_code [3];
    char number[];
}
```

And `sizeof(struct license_plate_v2)` does not include the `flexible array member`.

Comment: Ah, "the struct hack" seems exactly what I was looking for. Is it standard compliant? It seems to contradict your reference...

Comment: @ArtB Not technically, but because so much legacy code was written that way pre-standard, it can still be used in practice.  You still can't use such a struct as a member of an array, however.

Comment: @ArtB Also, the way you set up the `arr_1`, `arr_2`, `arr_3` pointers violates any alignment requirements that `struct licence_plate_v2` may have.

Comment: Why not? If each member had the same length of the variable indices are still calculatable (not with `[]` obviously but I seem to be able to work around it via `index_license_plate_v2`)

Comment: @ArtB You may be getting away with it because all the members of `struct license_plate_v2` have `char` alignment, so probably the struct as a whole has the same alignment requirement. If the struct contained something larger than a `char` it would break horribly on platforms that care about properly aligned types.

Comment: Would x86-64 be one of those platforms? I feel I need to learn a bit more about alignment. :(

Comment: @dbush: The authors of the C Standard recognized that one of the things that made C useful was the existence of "popular extensions" that defined behavior in cases where the Standard imposed no requirements but implementations behaved in ways appropriate for their target platforms and intended purposes.  Things like the "struct hack" and the "zero-size array extension" fall into that category.  Unfortunately, the fact that the Standard fails to mandate a feature is seen as being in and of itself a reason for compilers to go out of their way to assume programmers will never use it.

Comment: x86-64 is kind of one of those platforms. But not really. On x86/x86_64 unaligned access is cought by the CPU and handled. It's just slower than aligned access. On something like Alpha the code would cause an exception and the kernel had to emulate the access. On other systems it might even kill the program with a signal.

Comment: Another warning about alignment: sizeof(struct license_plate_v2) does not include the variable sized array but it does include the alignment. Specifically the compiler might add padding AFTER number to get the struct to align. You want to use offsetof(struct license_plate_v2, number) for the size calulation or you may waste memory.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: Given that it's not possible to perform arithmetic on a pointer type whose target is a structure with an FLA member, I don't think padding the size of such a structure to its alignment requirement serves any useful purpose.  Instead of forbidding FLA structures from being included in other structs, the Standard should much more usefully have required that the item following an FLA be an array of the same type, which would be placed to coincide with the FLA.  As it is, the vagueness with which FLAs are specified significantly undermines their usefulness.

Comment: @supercat what does you mean by  `"not possible to perform arithmetic on a pointer type whose target is a structure with an FLA member"` isn't that what  `index_license_plate_v2()` does? Remember in this question is the length of the VLA is _constant_ but it's not known till runtime, but it is fixed and known.

Comment: @ArtB: The pattern used by `index_license_plate_v2()` requires converting the pointer to a character type prior to doing arithmetic.  A compiler might as an extension accept code which tries to do arithmetic on a pointer to a structure that contains a FAM, but adding a byte-denominated size to a pointer of a non-character type is unlikely to yield desirable behavior.